# How can i log traffic activity of a GCP instance?

Tags: networking, firewall, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloud-computing

I keep getting warnings from GCP that i have suspicious activity on my GCP instance and they're right. I keep seeing huge traffic going to China in my billing as follows.

`Compute Engine Network Internet Egress from APAC to China`

i'm really worried about this. How can i log these traffic and is there any way to stop this from happening. I need to have all IPs allowed to the instance. Can i block traffic to china?

Answer (score 1):

You can use tcpdump to see & log the traffic.

What protocol is this? If it's HTTP or SSH you can look at fail2ban for automatically blocking traffic. If you're looking for a more in depth layer of protection OSSEC may fit the bill better. Both allow you to customize and add "checks".

Comment: Hi it's HTTP. I have totally forgotten `tcpdump`. Thank you. What i want to do is DROP all requests that origins from china. Is there any way i can do it from the VPC network? I know i can create firewall rules. But i don't know which IPs to block and if it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem on my linux boxes, I use iptables and create a rule to match ipset lists of countries that I want to allow. You could easily block countries using this method as well. I have found the following 2 sites to provide subnet lists https://www.countryipblocks.net/country_selection.php and http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/